# Как добавить функцию возврата иконки Play и остановки анимации, после завершения воспроизведения музыки в JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня такая проблема.
При завершении воспроизведения композиции, не происходит возврат иконки Play.
Продолжает стоять иконка Pause и соответственно небольшой блок анимации тоже не останавливается.
Как это исправить? Кто знает? Подскажите пожалуйста! Буду очень благодарен!
Нужно всего лишь дать команду на замену иконки Pause на Play и остановку анимации при завершении воспроизведения композиции.
[image: до воспроизведения]

[image: после нажатия на кнопку/иконку Play]

```
window.onload=function(){ $('.play-song img').on('click',function(e){ var song = e.currentTarget.dataset.song;

var songtoplay = document.querySelector(`[data-audio="${song}"]`);

//if song is playing pause it if (songtoplay.duration > 0 && !songtoplay.paused) {

songtoplay.pause()

songtoplay.classList.remove('playing')

this.src="images/play.png";

var sondindicator = document.querySelectorAll('.music-indicator-span');

sondindicator.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('animating'));


}

//if song is not playing play it and if another song is playing mute the other song

//also change the play button image to pause else {

if($('.playing') && $('.playing-symbol')){ var playing = document.querySelectorAll('.playing') playing.forEach(a=>a.pause()); playing.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('playing'));


var playingsymbol = document.querySelectorAll('.playing-symbol') playingsymbol.forEach(a=>a.src="images/play.png"); playingsymbol.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('playing-symbol')); }

songtoplay.play()

var sondindicator = document.querySelectorAll('.music-indicator-span');

sondindicator.forEach(a=>a.classList.add('animating'));


songtoplay.classList.add('playing') this.classList.add('playing-symbol')

this.src="images/pause.png"; } }) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Завершение воспроизведения композиции предусматривает соответствующее программное событие элемента аудио. Вот ему и можно задать возврат иконки play и отключение анимации:

```js
songtoplay.onended = function(){ // это событие завершения воспроизведения
    sondindicator.forEach(a=>a.classList.remove('animating'));
     // ... что-то ещё
    this.src = "images/play.png";
}
```

Comment: Отлично! Работает частично, только анимация как нужно стала реагировать.. Нужно ещё теперь добавить сюда же как-то, иконку и само аудио, чтобы также реагировали они!

Comment: Напишите полный код, разберёмся.

Comment: Всё, я разобрался) Ура, неужели)) Спасибо ОГРОООМНОЕ вам за помощь, очень помогли, действительно!!!

Comment: Чтобы было более точно, по нажатию на play должна появиться иконка предзагрузки, (вращающиеся точки) а по событию onload уже иконка паузы. Обычно предзагрузки идёт быстро и иконка предзагрузки быстро промелькивает.

Comment: Ну это уже не обязательно, с учётом самой структуры сайта.. Тот результат, который сейчас получился, как раз идеален для него!